# Win2012 R2 Server hanging after iSCSI install

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iscsi, qnap

**Issue: Server was experiencing hanging issues after 7 hours of uptime.
Server had no issues prior to addition of iSCSI. ?Temporarily? Resolved by reboot.**

**iSCSI Device**: QNAP TS-1263XU-4G-US 2U with 2x 1TB SSDs in Raid 1 configuration. No Snapshots.

**Server**: Windows 2012 R2, 4GHz FX4300, 16GB Ram. Using Microsoft's iSCSI. OS on SSD.

**Server/iSCSI responsibilities**:low-use SQL & file serving.

All devices are on gig ethernet.
Copy to/from the QNAP device proceeds at solid speeds.
There had been an issue with CHAP, but turned off CHAP for the interim.

**Scenario:**
Setup iSCSI, moved all data over to the new iSCSI interface, then switched drive letters on iSCSI drive with old spinning disk hard drive.
SQL and File Services ran, everything seemed fine. Rebooted twice, then checked again.
Everything Ok.

7 hours later, Server is ?hanging? Chrome takes multiple minutes loading, then hangs looking for cache when trying to access web interface for QNAP.
All processes slow, even processes that do not touch on the iSCSI.
Firefox won't load at all.
Failed to try testing the iSCSI read/write access during this time period. Called reboot of server - reboot took 10+ minutes but finished w/out crash. Issue gone after reboot.

Issue remains gone after waiting 2 hours. Nothing in the eventvwr that seems related.

**Edit**: Hang issue occurred overnight, when noone is using the server.

**Edit**: No other device on the network uses the qnap - QNAP is iSCSI'd to the server, server shares it out from there.

My apologies if I'm leaving a detail out, I'm new to iSCSI (2nd setup of an iSCSI device in my life).

**Edit**: iSCSI Applet configured in.. the normal way? Used the iSCSI applet in Control Panel. Did **not** configure MPIO. Applet asked to turn on service, allowed it to do so. Added QNAP device to iSCSI applet by it's short name, then configured the drive in diskmgmt.msc. 
**Edit**: Qnap has seemed in proper order - did not need to reboot qnap to fix the issue, just the server. Was able to access the generic shares on the qnap from other PCs - did not try to access the iSCSI interface, as I've been led to believe you shouldn't do that from 2 different PCs.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What iSCSI components did you install and configure? I'm assuming that you configured the iSCSI initiator. Is that correct?

Comment: It looks like the failure is more on the Qnap server than the Windows client. Did you try accessing the Qnap from another machine?

Comment: Well. Issue has not recurred. So I'm just going to chalk it up to gremlins.
To summarize: Issue occurred once. Rebotoed server, issue went away. Has not recurred since. Never had to reboot the qnap to resolve. 
My apologies.